# How can I create instance of HttpRequestHeaders class

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have to unit test class that use HttpRequestHeaders as parameter.

```
    public HeaderValueProvider(HttpRequestHeaders headers)
    {
        _headers = headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 31):

`HttpRequestHeaders` has only internal constructor.
But you can do it by creating `HttpRequestMesssage` object:

```
using var headers = new HttpRequestMessage().Headers;
```

Comment: Thank you. A solution that does not create a full-fledged `HttpClient` feels much better. Note that `HttpRequestMessage` is disposable, so you may want to place is in a `using` block.

Comment: @Timo, you are right. 
With c# 8.0 you can write:
`using var headers = new HttpRequestMessage().Headers;`

Comment: That really looks like it would dispose the headers rather than the `HttpRequestMessage`. Are you absolutely sure that does what you intend? Maybe there's some magic that I'm not aware of...

Comment: Timo you are right. It should be:

```C#
  using var message = new HttpRequestMessage(); 
  var headers = message.Headers; 
```

Answer (score 19):

You can get a blank instance of `HttpRequestHeaders` via:

```
var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way that doesn't require constructing any resources is using `Activator`. There's a special argument `nonPublic` of `Activator.CreateInstance`.

> nonPublic: true if a public or nonpublic parameterless constructor can match; false if only a public parameterless constructor can match.

Here's an example of this working:

```csharp
var headers = (HttpRequestHeaders)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HttpRequestHeaders), nonPublic: true);
```

And a .NET Fiddle demonstrating it in use: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YmW1T8